# Finding UTM coordinates of intersection points using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have two line layers, and I would like to generate a another column that shows the UTM coordinates of each intersection point.

How do I do it?

My code:

```
Select st_intersects(b.geom, a.geom), st_intersection(b.geom, a.geom)
From afile as a, bfile as b
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you wish to ask a similar question about using PyQGIS then please do that in a separate question and include a code attempt.

Comment: One of the reasons that use of FROM lists has been phased out of SQL best practice was its vulnerability to polynomial expansion if a WHERE clause wasn't provided. If you had used a JOIN, there would have to be an ON clause which would limit output to combinations where `ST_Intersects` evaluated true, which would have gotten you closer to your goal. You may need to handle MULTIPOINT intersection, or even GEOMETRYCOLLECTION results with both point and line overlap, but even for simple POINT intersection, you still need to extract the ST_X and ST_Y from the intersection geometry.